# Difference between Group signature scheme and Public key Crypto

Tags: java, cryptography

While studying an implementation of Group signature I came across code where Group certificate is generated and signed using Pricvate key of RSA algo(LibGS library TestACJTGroupManager.java link:http://www.ing.unibs.it/ntw/tools/pp2db/). I'm confused about the scheme of Group sign. Pls help me out.

Comment: [crypto](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What are you confused about?

- [Public key/private key](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public_key) is a technique for asymmetric cryptography
- [RSA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA_%28algorithm%29) is one algorithm for implementing the technique.  It's also the name of a company.  Which consists of the initials of the three guys who invented the technique (Ron Rivest, Adi Shamir, and Leonard Adleman).
- [Group Signatures](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_signature) are one application of this technique